JSON in SharePoint: Conditional Formatting by Column Based on Relative Date
I'm using a SharePoint List to track annual training requirements. I would like for the column to display different colors based on the date they have entered into the field relative to when they need to accomplish the training again. So, what I'm trying to accomplish:

365 or more = red
<365 = green
304-364 (60 days till expiration) = yellow
Date is displayed in white regardless of above

Here's what I have so far (lifted from another answer and modified slightly):
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField >= @now - 31449600000 ,'green', (if(@currentField > @now - 31536000000, '#F07440','red'))"
  }
}


Could you define the requirement logic a little bit clearly? @currentField older than 365 days from current date is 'Red', between 304 and 364 is green. What is the logic for Yellow and White? Need to make sure the logic incorporate all days

I see where the confusion lies. Let me amend the conditions to be more clear:
366 or more = red
365-305 (expiring within 60 days) = yellow
0-304 = green

Here is what I can come up with. Of course, you could modify to suit your needs.
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField <= (@now - (86400000 *365)), 'red', if((@currentField <=  (@now - (86400000 *304)) &&  @currentField >= (@now - (86400000 *364))), 'yellow', 'green'))",
    "font-size": "12px",
    "font-weight": "bold",
    "justify-content": "center",
    "color": "=if((@currentField <=  (@now - (86400000 *304))) &&  (@currentField >= (@now - (86400000 *364))), 'black', 'white')"
  }
}




Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.
Is there a way to gray out a cell based on the value of another cell? Example:
If the record's Supervisor column = "Yes", "Training" = grayed out.
If the record's Supervisor column = "No", "Training" = date formatting applied

Yes, that is possible. You can refer other column (not the current column being formatted) like [$DueDate] in the condition.  For more info visit this reference link

Also mark this question as answered and post a new question with the detailed requirements
